# How would I retrieve live website data and print it to a text widget in python GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

I had done this a while ago but just trying to remember the steps needed in order to pull certain text within tags using regex and then print it to a GUI text widget to display it? Not sure how to print a text or HTML file either to the text widget.

```
file_contents = open('download111.txt')
contents = file_contents.read()
file_contents.close()

results = findall("[A-Z]+", contents)
for result in results:
    print(results)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO :) . The question is unclear to us. Do you need help in fetching the content from website and parsing the HTML to get the text between tags OR you don't know how to create a Label in tkinter with text on it? In other words, do you need help with pulling  text, regex OR the GUI creation ?

Comment: Hi, It was pulling text with regex and then printing it to the text widget

Comment: Alright. What part of it you have problems with? regardless I'm writing an answer for both the cases.

Comment: It is creating a function or changing previous functions e.g. when clicking a button it will call a command to fetch live website data and then print it to either a text widget or a list box. With regex

Comment: Alright. Do check the answer after a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer will cover two of your main queries. Those are

- pulling some useful text from a website and getting a certain part of it based on our `regex`
- Displaying that info on the `tkinter.text` widget on a button click

At the very end, there will be a complete example with button and function.

## First Part

We will put this code in a function block because we want to connect it to a button. I will explain the code here.
I will use `requests` module to get the whole `webpage` from web and use `BeautifulSoup4` to `parse` the HTML to pull out some certain text and then use `regex` to make final cuts on that text.

```
 # use your preferred import style

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs   
import requests as rq

content = rq.get('https://www.cricbuzz.com/live-cricket-scores/30384/kxip-vs-mi-13th-match-indian-premier-league-2020')
```

the example webpage I used is [This Page](https://www.cricbuzz.com/live-cricket-scores/30384/kxip-vs-mi-13th-match-indian-premier-league-2020), a coverage of the cricket game last night.
NOTE THAT you can also read from a downloaded file to find `regex` matches instead of pulling data directly from the website.

On this page, there is lot of stuff but I only need to know the result (say) which is `Mumbai Indians won by 48 runs`.

The `content` variable above now holds the entire HTML `response` from the webpage.
We will `parse` that entire HTML text with `BeautifulSoup`. [Click Here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#quick-start) for an excellent intro on how to quick start with BS4.

```
parsedContent = bs(s.text, 'html.parser') # check the BS4 & requests docs above to know more about these functions
```

Here comes the tricky part..
We have to fetch what we need from this parsed HTML content. There are so many ways to do this as described [HERE](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree). IT ALSO HAS INFO ON USING REGEX, HIGHLY RECOMMEND YOU CHECK THIS OUT.

I will use the method of `find_all()` from `BeautifulSoup` using the class id (I'm talking about the CSS class ID here not to be confused by class keyword in python)

I can use the developer tool of any browser to know what the class id of an element is. This approach depends on how the webpage is formatted. Use an approach suitable for you from the [DOCS](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree).

Check below image[image: Class id of div]
for example.

the code to find this division is -

```
res = parsedContent.find_all('div', 'cb-col cb-col-100 cb-min-stts cb-text-complete')
# here class id is ->> cb-col cb-col-100 cb-min-stts cb-text-complete
```

`res` variable now holds the value as below

```
[<div class="cb-col cb-col-100 cb-min-stts cb-text-complete">Mumbai Indians won by 48 runs</div>]
```

which is a `list` because we used `find_all()` which returns a list even if there is only 1 match.

the variable `res[0]` is the actual piece we will consider as it is the only value in the list.
`res[0]` variable now has some info which is mix up of HTML tags and actual text between them.
As the `res[0]` is a parsed HTML text, we can use `res[0].string` to get actual text between those tags.

```
actualText = res[0].string
```

Now You have a normal python string of text to work with, it has no HTML or CSS elements. You can use your `regex` pattern on this string to grab what you want (or as I said above you can use regex with `find_all` method)

Now that we have a text that we need to show, we can talk about GUI.

## Second part - GUI

This is fairly easy.

```
import tkinter as tk
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def get_content():
    # the code to pull website content and applying regex here. full example below

root = tk.Tk()
tk.Button(root, text='Get content from website', command=get_content).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The `Text` widget will be created inside the function `get_content()` .

## Complete example

```
import tkinter as tk
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def get_content():
    content = rq.get('https://www.cricbuzz.com/live-cricket-scores/30384/kxip-vs-mi-13th-match-indian-premier-league-2020')
    parsedContent = bs(content.text, 'html.parser') # check the BS4 & requests docs above to know more about these functions
    res = parsedContent.find_all('div', 'cb-col cb-col-100 cb-min-stts cb-text-complete')
    # here class id is ->> cb-col cb-col-100 cb-min-stts cb-text-complete
    actualText = res[0].string
    # Apply regex now if needed

    # CREATING a text widget to display the info.
    output_widget = tk.Text(root, bg='#fff', fg='#000')
    output_widget.pack()
    output_widget.insert(tk.END, actualText)

root = tk.Tk()
tk.Button(root, text='Get content from website', command=get_content).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Please Note:

1. If by any chance `requests` take longer time to get data from website, it might cause the GUI to freeze for that amount of time. This happens because the code execution doesn't reach `mainloop()` of `tkinter` which is responsible for updating the GUI. The only way round this is parallel execution using either of [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) or [multi-processing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) or [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) .
2. The ability to find content from website (using class ids or regexes or other parameters) depends on how deeply you understand the [BeautifulSoup Docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#beautiful-soup-documentation).

Comment: Was it possible to not use...'import requests as rq' and 
'from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs' ?

Comment: As I mentioned, you can use your preferred import style. `import requests` , `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` also work. If you are asking - Do I really have to use `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` modules, then the answer is Maybe Not if we can figure out some other way to get data from website. We used both modules because they are the most suitable for these needs. Just FYI, you can use requests to download a file from the web as well. If you already have a downloaded file some text in it, and you want to grab some part based on regex, without  a website, Then yes you can avoid those modules.

Comment: i will use from "urllib.request import urlopen", "from webbrowser import open as urldisplay". It it possible to use these?

Comment: It might be possible but how will you get the text from the website in that case? (I haven't used them much so I'm not sure)